# Find causal relations between multiple branches of science

Tags: machine-learning

I have no basic understanding of data science. I got this idea of comparing data and finding causal relationships from different branches of science. For example, find out if there are any relations between astronomy and the economy, or if I choose to drink soda or water for lunch, and does that relate to the fly pattern of an insect.

I want to act on this idea and try to manifest it, but I have no idea if it is possible or how it works. My question is basically, is it possible to create such a software. If yes, how can I create such a software. I am a professional developer, so I have experience in programming.

Comment: This question is way too broad and generic for SO. There are plenty of online resources that will introduce you to statistics, data science and machine learning. You can get a basic understanding of these disciplines if you just use Google. This will require time and effort on your part. Once you have done your research and have an actual problem that you need help with, then it is time to post here.

Comment: @Vlad_Z Thank you for your input. I knew this was a fallacy on my part, that I needed to do some research on my own first. Thank you for confirming my assumption, and I will peruse the internet for more information. When I have reached a deeper understanding and in case I need help, I will return with a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing seems way too broad for something as strong and as complex as causality. Causality is hard to determine because of the existence of confounders - variables that are associated with both the response variable (such as the fly pattern of an insect) AND the explanatory variable (whether you drink soda). An example: perhaps you drink more soda during hot days and flies also move their wings faster during hotter days. You need to either design an experiment that carefully uses randomization to get absolute causal claims or perhaps record as many potential confounders as possible and add these to perhaps a statistical model to control for confounding effects (to get weaker causal conclusions if they exist).

Your question is too broad to possibly control for all of these confounders - especially the "is astronomy related to economy" question. In what specific way do you think they are related? Do you mean something such as if the economy tanks, does this cause astromomy research to fall? The fly example you provide is a bit better but still would be difficult. Do you even have reason to believe that these two phenomena are causally linked apriori before the experiment? Is there sound theory thay supports such a conclusion before you even collect data or write a single line of code? Causality is tricky and in general you first come up with sound reasoning to believe why two phenomena are linked first.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am aware of the sheer scope of this idea. The reason why I want to do this, is because I believe that everything is related to everything else, in the same way as Quantum entanglement describes it, and then I thought, if it works on the fundamental level, does it work the same way on a higher level of abstraction? The thing with the astronomy and economy was meant like this: If a planet x is in a specific place or alignment, does it impact the economy in a specific way?

Comment: @Gautama many people have tried to demonstrate the scientific validity of astrology, which claims to predict events based on observing planets. Nobody succeeded so far.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the major issues described in other answers and comments, the technological limitations of current AI methods are absolutely insufficient for such high level of abstraction in causality reasoning.

Let's assume this would be operationalized using on a corpus of scientific articles from various domains (this part is ok) using Natural Language Processing (NLP) methods. The state of the art in NLP doesn't even reach satisfying levels of performance in detecting direct causality between two sentences, a task that humans can do quite well. This means that the most basic step required for this problem is not even doable, let alone complex reasoning across different domains.